# images not showing from application layout

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

I have an image in my `application.html.erb`. It is showing properly in my root view, but when i move to `login` that image disaapears. The image I am talking about is ChainLogo.png. any ideas what i am doing wrong?

my root layout for now looks like this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "home", :media => "all" %>
<div id="home_log_in">
    <%= link_to 'Log-in', login_index_path %>
</div>
```

my application.html.erb looks like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Chain</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>
    <div id="main_banner"> </div>
    <div id="main_logo"><img src="assets/images/ChainLogo.png"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

and my login.html.erb looks like so:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "login", :media => "all" %>

<div id="signin_form">  
    <%=form_for :user  do |f| %>

        <%= f.text_field :email, :id => "email_input", :placeholder => "enter email" %>             
    <div id="signmeup_button">
        <%= f.text_field :password, :id => '"password', :placeholder => "enter password"%>
    </div>

    <div id="just_email_signup">
        <%= f.submit %> 

    <% end %>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this `<img src="assets/images/ChainLogo.png">` please use rails tag to append image i.e. `<%= image_tag "ChainLogo.png" %>` in your application.html.erb file.